# AES Decryption doesn't work

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I am developing a client-server application using sockets where the client sends encrypted JSON data using Cipher AES-256 encryption and the server takes in charge of decrypting those files received and print them out.

I tried it on the localhost the decryption worked but when I set my Centos Server it didn't work. The encrypted data coming from the client are received but not decrypted.

here is the server code:

**Server code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import threading
import Encryption


class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

def listen(self):
    self.sock.listen(5)
    while True:
        client, address = self.sock.accept()
        client.settimeout(60)
        threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

def listenToClient(self, client, address):
    size = 4096
    while True:
        print("Receiving")
        try:
            data = client.recv(size)
            if data:
                cipher = Encryption.Encryption('mysecretpassword')
                jsondata = cipher.decrypt(data)
                print(jsondata)
                self.request.close()
            else:
                raise socket.error('Client disconnected')
        except:
            client.close()
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ThreadedServer(adress,port).listen()
```

and the Encryption file is inspired from [here](https://gist.github.com/swinton/8409454)

Comment: the problem I'm seeing would be if data size is > 4096. in that case the data would be truncated right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the data size is definitely smaller than 4096. Besides, I tried this on localhost and it worked just fine so it is not related to the data size.

Comment: Nevertheless, the line `data = client.recv(size)` *incorrectly* assumes that a message boundary will correspond with a packet boundary. That may happen occasionally, but it cannot be relied upon. You must use some reliable method to allow the server to determine when a message ends, such as prefixing each network message with a 4-byte big-endian length value.

Comment: The problem I had is a compatibility problem.. I will write the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is a compatibility version in the unpad lambda function:

**Python 2**

```
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]
```

**Python 3**

```
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-s[-1]]
```

Comment: Ugh, don't you hate it when a language has these kind of breaks between versions (could be worse though, it could be PHP). Note that you can accept your own answer after a day or two (you won't get any reputation for that, obviously, but you do get rep for upvotes).

Comment: Well, it can't be avoided! I lacked knowledge that's all. I need to pay more attention to details like this in the future! I will accept may answer in two days.

Comment: Great. Thanks for reporting back, I'll keep this one in the back of my mind. And welcome to StackOverflow of course.

Comment: Thank you @MaartenBodewes :)